# Terrafrom & MySQL: Access denied

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-mysql

I have the following code:

```
provider "mysql" {
  alias = "rails_production"
  endpoint = var.mysql_rails_production_host
  username = var.mysql_rails_production_user
  password = var.mysql_rails_production_password
}

resource "mysql_user" "michael_b" {
  provider = mysql.rails_production
  user = "michael.b"
  host = "%"
}

resource "mysql_user_password" "michael_b" {
  provider = mysql.rails_production
  user = mysql_user.michael_b.user
  host = mysql_user.michael_b.host
  pgp_key = "keybase:USER"
}

resource "mysql_grant" "michael_b" {
  provider = mysql.rails_production
  user = mysql_user.michael_b.user
  host = mysql_user.michael_b.host
  database = "production"
  privileges = ["SELECT"]
}
```

And the following error:

```
1044: Access denied for user 'terraform'@'%' to database 'mysql'

on rails_production.tf line 7, in resource "mysql_user_password" "michael_b":
   7: resource "mysql_user_password" "michael_b"
```

I don't really understand. I'm pretty sure the user `terraform` has access to the `mysql` table; I've logged to the db with the user and run a few queries, everything looks good. I can even access the `mysql` table.

And if I run a:

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'terraform'@'%'
```

I get:

```
GRANT SELECT, SHOW DATABASES, CREATE USER ON *.* TO 'terraform'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION
```

Any ideas?

Comment: debug mode give any useful info: https://www.terraform.io/docs/internals/debugging.html ?
(I can only think it's trying to do something outside the scope of the grants)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the mysql terraform user privleges.  The `UPDATE` privlege is missing.

Update the terraform user privleges in the mysql database so that when you run

`SHOW GRANTS FOR 'terraform'@'%'`

you get

`GRANT SELECT, UPDATE, SHOW DATABASES, CREATE USER ON *.* TO 'terraform'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION`

instead of

`GRANT SELECT, SHOW DATABASES, CREATE USER ON *.* TO 'terraform'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION`